# Java Inheritance without casting

Tags: java, oop, generics, binary-tree

```
public class BinaryVertex {
  public BinaryVertex parent,left,right;
}

public class BSTVertex extends BinaryVertex {
  public void foo() {
    left = new BSTVertex();
    if(Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 0) left.foo();
  }
}
```

I'm making a tree / graph api for school, approaching it from a oop standpoint. But im trying to figure out a way for the inherited class to treat some of its base class variables as its own type (i.e. parent,left,right should be treated as `BSTVertex` when called from `BSTVertex` but treated as `BinaryVertex` when called from `BinaryVertex`) without casting.

I'm thinking of generics but I'm not sure how to implement that in this situation.

### UPDATE

Nice, didnt know you could use extend in generics. But I'm getting a `BSTVertex<T> cannot be converted to T` error with this:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  new AVLVertex();
  BSTVertex<BSTVertex> v = new BSTVertex<BSTVertex>();
  v.foo();
}
class BinaryVertex<T extends BinaryVertex> {
  public T parent, left, right;
}
class BSTVertex<T extends BSTVertex> extends BinaryVertex<T> {
  public T foo() {
    return this; //error here
  }
}
class AVLVertex extends BSTVertex<AVLVertex> {
  // this might probably end up being abstract too
}
```

foo needs to return a vertex of the same type as caller, i.e. if AVLVertex calls foo its expecting to get AVLVertex not BSTVertex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use generics like this:

```
public class BinaryVertex<T extends BinaryVertex<T>> {
    public T parent, left, right;
}

public class BSTVertex extends BinaryVertex<BSTVertex> {
  public void foo() {
    left = new BSTVertex();
    if(Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 0) left.foo();
  }
}
```

The same way the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface implemented, so subclasses receive the same type to `compareTo` method. For example, `Integer implements Comparable<Integer>`, so its `compareTo` method receives `Integer` argument.

Also please note the it would be better to create your own random number generator like this:

```
public class BSTVertex extends BinaryVertex<BSTVertex> {
  private static final Random r = new Random();
  public void foo() {
    left = new BSTVertex();
    if(r.nextBoolean()) left.foo();
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

In your updated code (in future please ask new question instead) you cannot safely cast, because you can potentially write later:

```
class RBVertex extends BSTVertex<RBVertex>{}
class AVLVertex extends BSTVertex<RBVertex>{}
```

This is ok from the compiler's point of view, but your `AVLVertex` generic argument is actually not an `AVLVertex`. That's why you have a compilation error in `foo()` method: your class can be later possibly extended in the way that would make your `T` incompatible with this.

You can fix this problem by doing an unchecked cast:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public T foo() {
    return (T) this;
}
```

In this way if you mistakenly create `class AVLVertex extends BSTVertex<RBVertex>{}`, it will still compile, but upon calling `AVLVertex.foo()` you may have a runtime `ClassCastException`.

Comment: thanks for the info on extending generics! im still having some issues with my implementation though, hope you can help (see updated post) :)